# New line manully in GlyphLayout

Tags: libgdx

There is a need to start a new line when drawing text manually.
But `\n` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
gl=new GlyphLayout();
font=Assets.getFont(10);
gl.setText(font, text, Color.WHITE, cam.getDims().x-cam.getDims().x/10, Align.left, true);
font.draw(sb, gl, -(cam.getDims().x-cam.getDims().x/10)/2, -cam.getDims().y/6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` contains `\\n`, not `\n`. Replacing `\` and `n` with `\n` solves this issue.